# React + jersey + spring + Tomcat 9 CORS

Tags: reactjs, spring, rest, jersey

I'm having a problem and can't figure out wheres the error.
I have a simple React frontend that I'm using to try to send a POST request to some REST services I have running on a Tomcat 9 server. I've read that POST methods need CORS to allow origin, I've configured web.xml from my app like this:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:3000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>100</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My React code id as follows:

```
const payload = {
  username: "Diego",
  password: "PASS"
}
var data = new FormData();
data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );

const Prueba = () => {
  fetch(loginurl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: data
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(jsondata => console.log(jsondata))
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Were loginurl is the url to the following REST service

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response login(User userParam) {
    System.out.println("UserParam.Username: " + userParam.getUsername() + "\tUserParam.Password: " + userParam.getPassword());
    User user = this.userLogic.getUserByUsername("diego");
    return Response.status(200).entity(user).build();
}
```

If I call the service using the Advanced RestClient chrome extension, it works great, but when using the React code the server throws the following:

```
Apr 25, 2018 3:00:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jersey-spring] in context with path [/socialmedia] threw exception [org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5a63d6f9; line: 1, column: 3]] with root cause
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5a63d6f9; line: 1, column: 3]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1432)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserBase.reportUnexpectedNumberChar(JsonParserBase.java:960)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._handleInvalidNumberStart(Utf8StreamParser.java:2210)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.parseNumberText(Utf8StreamParser.java:1005)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._nextTokenNotInObject(Utf8StreamParser.java:598)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.nextToken(Utf8StreamParser.java:486)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2761)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2682)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleSimpleCORS(CorsFilter.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

UPDATE: POST payload from chrome

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryZv1Ml2SgmeIwrn21
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{"username":"Diego","password":"PASS"}
------WebKitFormBoundaryZv1Ml2SgmeIwrn21--
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?
Thanks for your help!!
Diego

Comment: You can see in the error, it is saying `Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value`. Check your request body. What value it is sending. Or post the request body from network tab of chrome.

Comment: Chrome doesn't show me the payload, it shows onlye a "General" panel and a "Request Headers" panel, any other way to see the body? :(

Comment: All this info about the chrome dev tools you can find here https://developer.chrome.com/devtools look for network tab. Payload will  show under header tab of network tab. By the way you have to click on the request to see it.

Comment: thanks, I restarted the servers and now shows all the datam don't know what happened =/ added the payload to original post, dont know what ------WebKitFormBoundaryZv1Ml2SgmeIwrn21 means

Comment: Is that what showing under `Request payload`? It should only show the object `{"username":"Diego","password":"PASS"}`

Comment: yes, thats the info under Request Payload, which corresponds to the error of "Unexpected character" but don't know why or how to correct this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is request is encoded as `FormData`.

Instead of using `new FormData()` and `append`.

Just use `JSON.stringify`.

```
var data = JSON.stringify( payload );

const Prueba = () => {
  fetch(loginurl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: data
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(jsondata => console.log(jsondata))
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

If you are developing a complex application, I recommend [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Comment: Thank you!! that solves the payload problem, now I'm receiving a 415 but thats another problem, I'll make another post if I can't find the solution. THANKS I was going crazy with this one!

Comment: Check the request headers. It may not be encoded properly. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415

Comment: that was it, I had removed the Content-Type making some tests and forgot to add it back, thanks!